# PHP '&&' operator issue or misunderstood

Tags: php, codeigniter, boolean, isset

Hy,

I am developing a small site based on PHP and CodeIgniter. I met a very-very strange behavior today. I have the following code to check if a field is filled or not:

```
$valid = isset ( $model->{$property} ) && !empty($model->{$property});
error_log ( $valid );
```

I expecting '$valid' to be true if '$model->{property}' exsists and not empty. Unfortunately I got the following output from 'error_log()' function regardless of the property exists or not, has value or not:

```
[Sat Oct 11 19:49:43 2014] [error] [client 192.168.2.68] , referer: http://192.168.2.248:8080/
```

What is wrong? Is there any other (better) ways to check if a property exists *and* filled?

Comment: `!empty` is an alias for `isset && !!`, meaning it's set and not falsy. There is no need to manually test `isset` if you're testing `!empty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for dumb question: I was wrong. The model I posted via AJAX actually not contains the expected fields.

I found the problem in my JS codes. I am tried to post the form data with the following commands:

```
var formData = $(form).serialize();

$(form + " :input").attr("disabled", true);
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: action,
    data: formData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: postSuccess,
    error: postFail
    });
```

I tought $(form).serialize() extracts values from the form, and I am able to disable the input fields. Unfortunately not. I have to put disabling input fiends *after* the ajax call to pass correctly the values (.serialize() ignores disabled fields)